# Clojure performance on set updates or large number computations

Tags: performance, clojure

I'm trying to sum up prime numbers for an Euler project problem using the sieve algorithm.  I'm using a mutable set to store numbers that aren't prime and using 'dosync' and 'commute' to update the set (otherwise I ran out of memory if it was immutable) .  Performance is roughly linear up till 1.2 million primes, but performance is terrible at 1.5 million (7 seconds vs. 64 seconds).  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  My guess is that possibly numbers are getting too large, or maybe updating mutable sets is inefficient.

```
(defn mark-multiples [not-prime-set multiple prime-max]
  (loop [ counter (long 2) 
      product (* counter multiple)]
    (if (> product prime-max) not-prime-set
      (do
        (dosync (commute not-prime-set conj product))
        (recur  (inc counter) (* (inc counter) multiple))))))


(defn sieve-summation [prime-max]
  (def not-prime-set (ref #{ (long 1) }) )
  (loop [counter (long 2)
     summation (long 0)]
    (if (> counter prime-max) summation
      (if (not (contains? @not-prime-set counter)) 
        (do 
          (mark-multiples not-prime-set counter prime-max)
          (recur  (inc counter) (+ summation counter)))
        (recur (inc counter) summation)))))
```

=> (time (sieve-summation 100000))
"Elapsed time: 496.673 msecs"
454396537

=> (time (sieve-summation 150000))
"Elapsed time: 763.333 msecs"
986017447

=> (time (sieve-summation 1000000))
"Elapsed time: 6037.926 msecs"
37550402023

=> (time (sieve-summation 1100000))
"Elapsed time: 6904.385 msecs"
45125753695

=> (time (sieve-summation 1200000))
"Elapsed time: 7321.299 msecs"
53433406131

=> (time (sieve-summation 1500000))
"Elapsed time: 64995.216 msecs"
82074443256

----Edit----

Thanks A. Webb, great suggestion! The code you had was a bit slower, so in order to get it to speed up, I had to make the not-prime-set transient at the very beginning and now it runs faster (roughly 8 times). I'm still getting out-of-memory errors, so I'll try to figure out how to increase the heap size on the jvm to see if that fixes it.  I'm running Clojure on Eclipse on a Mac, and I'm new to Clojure and Macs.

I would be interested to see how you could further refactor the program (keeping mostly the same logic) to be more elegant in Clojure. Thanks again.

```
(defn mark-multiples2 [not-prime-set prime prime-max]
  (loop [multiple (* 2 prime) nps not-prime-set ]
    (if (> multiple prime-max) 
      nps
      (recur (+ multiple prime) (conj! nps multiple)))))


(defn sieve-summation2 [prime-max]
  (loop [counter 2, summation 0, not-prime-set (transient #{1})]
    (if (> counter prime-max) 
      summation
      (if (not-prime-set counter) 
        (recur (inc counter) summation not-prime-set)
        (recur (inc counter) 
           (+ summation counter) 
           (mark-multiples2 not-prime-set counter prime-max))))))
```

=> (time (sieve-summation2 100000))
"Elapsed time: 124.781 msecs"
454396537

=> (time (sieve-summation 100000))
"Elapsed time: 876.744 msecs"
454396537

Comment: What's the heap size of your jvm? I don't see that degradation with -Xmx1G

Comment: You should use Clojure 1.6 - hashing was overhauled and it might be better for this particular use case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.  What do you all recommend for running Clojure on a Mac?  I appreciate any up votes to get my reputation up :)

Comment: Leiningen (lein) is all you should need besides your editor of choice. Install directly from the site, as package managers provide outdated versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are much better and more elegant ways to solve this problem in Clojure, but that's not the point of your question.

Using a reference type -- whether it be a ref, or more appropriately an atom -- does nothing for you here. You are still creating just as much garbage. You are simply swapping out the contents of an mutable storage location from one immutable data structure to another. I don't know what caused your time spike, but one possibility is that you triggered a long garbage collection cycle.

What you want to use here are [transients](http://clojure.org/transients). Without changing your code too much, the following should be a significant speed-up.

```
(defn mark-multiples [not-prime-set multiple prime-max]
  (loop [m (* 2 multiple), nps (transient not-prime-set)]
    (if (> m prime-max) 
      (persistent! nps)
      (recur (+ m multiple) (conj! nps m)))))


(defn sieve-summation [prime-max]
  (loop [counter 2, summation 0, not-prime-set #{1}]
    (if (> counter prime-max) 
      summation
      (if (contains? not-prime-set counter) 
        (recur (inc counter) summation not-prime-set)
        (recur (inc counter) 
               (+ summation counter) 
               (mark-multiples not-prime-set counter prime-max))))))
```

This is the same algorithm, in more idiomatic style:

```
(defn mark [s n m]
  (into s (range (* 2 n) m n)))

(defn prime-sum [m]
  (let [step (fn [[a s] n] 
               (if (s n)
                 [a s] 
                 [(+ a n) (mark s n m)]))]
  (first (reduce step [0 #{}] (range 2 m)))))
```

From here, you might start to attack the inherent memory problem of your algorithm -- you are storing all non-primes, whereas you need only store the next non-primes at any given point. For a beautiful implementation of that idea, see Christophe Grand's [Everybody loves the Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/07/30/everybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes/) entry.

Comment: I edited my question above with the code to make it faster.  I appreciate any other suggestions you have, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idiomatic style. It took me some time to figure out how the reduce was working, pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the counterclockwise plugin for Eclipse and it was using Clojure 1.5, I believe because I had jdk 1.6.  I upgraded to jdk 1.7, and updated project.clj to use Clojure 1.6.0 and none of the memory/speed issues were a problem.
Thanks for the suggestions.